# Using DRF and React for Contact form

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I haven't seen anybody accept the form like this using DRF. I'm practically listing all of the fields for the POST method. Is it safe to do so?

```
class ContactForm(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
queryset = Contact.objects.all()
serializer_class = ContactSerializer

@action(methods=['GET'], detail=True)
def testing_env(self):
    return Response({'Works': 'ayyy'})

@action(methods=['POST'], detail=True)
def create_contact(self, request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    contact = Contact.objects.create(name=data['name'], email=data['email'], subject=data['subject'], message=data['message'])
    contact.save()
    return Response({'Success': 'it went good'})
```

And here's the React Form:

```
    handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = this.state
   axios({
       method: 'post',
       url: FormURL(),
       data:{
           name: this.state.name,
           email: this.state.email,
           subject: this.state.subject,
           message: this.state.message,
       }
   })
    
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it might not be safe? Also, consider using DRF serializers rather than creating the contact yourself. It'll make the validation logic easier.

Comment: I just thought it was too naive. I saw others installing different packages and doing all that crazy logic. Perhaps I found a better and easier way to validate forms